# JPA Secondary Table XML Config

Tags: jpa

I am working on a project where I need to store an Entity, which is unmodifiable (from library), so I am using XML entity mappings entity object is like:

```
public abstract class BaseModel{
    Long uid;
    //getters/setters
}

public abstract class LocaleBaseModel{
    String locale;
    //Other properties, getter/setters
} 

public class Article extends LocaleBaseModel{
    private Long authorId;
    privaet String text;
    //Other properties        
}

<mapped-superclass class="package.BaseModel">
    <attributes>
        <id name="uid">
            <column name="UID" nullable="false" />
            <generated-value strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>
    </attributes>
</mapped-superclass>
<mapped-superclass class="package.LocaleBaseModel">
    <secondary-table name="STableName">
        <primary-key-join-column name="MID" referenced-column-name="UID" />
    </secondary-table>
    <attributes>
        <basic name="locale">
            <column name="LOCALE" updatable="false" nullable="false" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="text">
            <column name="Text" updatable="false" nullable="false" table="STableName" />
        </basic>
    </attributes>
</mapped-superclass>

<entity class="package.child.Article" name="Hadith">
    <table name="TableName" />
    <attributes>

    </attributes>
</entity>
```

but as soon as I add `<secondarytable>` I  get an error which is quiet explanatory in itself:

> - 14:58:47,379 ERROR ErrorLogger:57 - Error parsing XML (2) :
>     cvc-complex-type.3.1: Value '2.0' of attribute 'version' of element
>     'entity-mappings' is not valid with respect to the corresponding
>     attribute use. Attribute 'version' has a fixed value of '1.0'.
> - 14:58:47,379 ERROR ErrorLogger:57 - Error parsing XML (2) :
>     cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>     element 'element-collection'. One of
>     '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":basic,
>     "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":version,
>     "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":many-to-one,
>     "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":one-to-many,
>     "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":one-to-one,
>     "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":many-to-many,
>     "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":embedded,
>     "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":transient}' is expected.
> - 14:58:47,379 ERROR ErrorLogger:57 - Error parsing XML (2) :
>     cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>     element 'secondary-table'. One of
>     '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":description,
>     "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":id-class,
>     "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":exclude-default-listeners,
>     "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":exclude-superclass-listeners,
>     "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":entity-listeners,
>     "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":pre-persist,
>     "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":post-persist,
>     "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":pre-remove,
>     "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":post-remove,
>     "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":pre-update,
>     "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":post-update,
>     "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":post-load,
>     "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":attributes}' is expected.

I have following on path, with others from spring 3.0.5

- hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.2
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api
- hibernate-core-3.6.2.Final

Answer (score 0):

according to the orm-schema

the secondary-table  elements likes to be placed
withing the

entity element  after the table tag

```
<pre> alike &lt;entity>
        &lt;table/>
        &lt;secondary-table/>
        ...
```

agreed the error message is noisy but that is 
the glorious schema spec.

ys.

Comment: What it suggests me is i can have secondary table for an entty, but if enetity is part of hierarchy defined via <mapped-superclass> it cannot control properties from super class to go into secondary table.